# In 'The Fractal Prince', how exactly does the Pellegrini steal Chen's code?

Tags: fractal-prince, jean-le-flambeur

I am not sure I understand the events in The Fractal Prince. What I think happens at the end is:

> The story line which Matjek speaks to the thief inside a vir happens after 
>  Matjek has caught the thief on the Earth. That is to say, Matjek speaks to 
>  what he assumes is a gogol of the thief, whereas in reality it is the 
>  all-defector that has escaped the dilemma prison 'inside' the thief.

What I do not understand is:

> How does the all-defector then proceed to steal Matjek's code? 
>  And why does it have to be the all-defector rather than the thief himself?
>  Also, is Matjek's code the moment of him experiencing the deaths of many 
>  people via the beemee?